# Why am I getting an error saying "expecting end" when I do have an end if?

Tags: vhdl, quartus, intel-fpga

Im trying to make a 4 bit adder/subtractor (Im trying to just get this to work before adding in 2s complement to it) and I keep getting these error messages:

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at ASU.vhd(16) near text "if";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at ASU.vhd(21) near text "else";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("else" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at ASU.vhd(26) near text "if";  expecting ";", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or "architecture"

the one thats really confusing me is where it says end if is expected because I did write an end if. If anyone could help me figure out where in my code I went wrong I would greatly appreciate it!
here is my code so far:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY ASU IS
PORT (Cin  : IN STD_LOGIC;
     X, Y: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        S   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        Cout, Overflow : out std_logic);
END ASU;

ARCHITECTURE Behaviour OF ASU IS
   signal Sum : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN

if Cin = '1' then 
   sum     <= ('0'& X)-('0'&Y);
   S       <= SUM(3 DOWNTO 0);
   Cout    <= Sum(3);
   Overflow <= Sum(4) XOR X(3) XOR Y(3) XOR Sum(3);
else
    sum     <= ('0'&X)+('0'&Y);
    S       <= SUM(3 DOWNTO 0);
    Cout    <= Sum(3);
    Overflow <= Sum(4) XOR X(3) XOR Y(3) XOR Sum(3); 
end if;

END Behaviour;
```

Comment: If you comment out the entire `if Cin = '1' then ` block and it still complains then the syntax error is somewhere before that block.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I ended up putting it inside a process and it worked, but this is an excellent suggestion and I will definitely be using it in the future!

Comment: An if statement (between from `if` to `end if` is a sequential statement and can only appear in a process statement (a concurrent statement) or subprogram body. Here you've got one in the architecture statement part, whose statements are all concurrent statements that either are processes, represent design hierarchy, or represent processes. Move the enire if statement into a process statement. Note the signal `Sum` should be declared with an index range 4 downto 0.

Comment: @user16145658 yes haha that was the next error I got once I put it inside a process. Its running now! thanks so much :)

Comment: There's also a [concurrent conditional signal assignment statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hym7h.jpg) which alleviates the need to put `Sum` in the process sensitivity list which requires multiple resumptions and subsequent suspensions of the process. In any event you require only single assignments to `Cout` and `Overflow`.

Comment: so is having sum in the process sensitivity list what's causing the program to take longer than usual to compile? I also noticed while trying to figure out twos complement that it is used for signed numbers, I believe here I have unsigned numbers so should I implement 1's complement instead?

Answer (score 1):

`if`, `else` and `endif` conditionals are sequential statements and, as such, can only appear inside a process.

Comment: ohhh got it thank you so much!

Comment: These reserved words are all part of the single if statement appearing in the question. In addition to in process statements sequential statements can appear in subprograms.